# django error: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting this error while I was trying to make two forms (with two models) and process that in the view. My SongForm is not saving its data in database while AlbumForm is perfectly saving its data.

views.py-

```
def formm(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    songform = SongForm(request.POST)
    albumform=AlbumForm(request.POST)
    if songform.is_valid() and albumform.is_valid():
        songform.save()
        albumform=albumform.save(commit=False)
        albumform.date=timezone.now()
        albumform.save()
        return redirect("result")
```

forms.py-

```
from django import forms
from . models import Album,Song

class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Song
        fields=('song_title','genre')

class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Album
        fields=('album_title',)
```

models.py-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    album_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.album_title

class Song(models.Model):
    song_title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album=models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.song_title
```

formmpage.html-

```
    {% extends "musicapp/basepage.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ songform.as_p }}
        {{ albumform.as_p }}


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">POST</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Do correct me, where actually I am doing wrong. I guess it is in my views.py.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, and please don't create multiple accounts to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you should be setting the song's album before you save it.

```
if songform.is_valid() and albumform.is_valid():
    album = albumform.save(commit=False)
    album.date = timezone.now()
    album.save()
    song = songform.save(commit=False)
    song.album = album
    song.save()
    return redirect("result")
```

Note that I changed the code to `album=albumform.save(commit=False)`, since the `save()` method returns a model instance, not a form instance.

Comment: thanks a lot. it is working now. can you tell me what this  line of code does, 'song.album=album' ?

Comment: Your `Song` model has a foreign key to `Album`. You were getting the error because you were trying to create a `Song` without setting the album. The `song.album = album` sets the new song's `album` to the new album you just created.

Comment: also, could you tell me, what left side album is and what actually is the right side, album in 'song.album = album' ? i am just the beginner in django. :)

Comment: The `album` on the right hand side is the `album` that you created when you saved the album form with `album = albumform.save(commit=False)`. You are assigning this to the song's album field, `song.album`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,I was certain this was the issue but i've used the code you've given me and I get an integrity error due to the fact that your Song model has a Foreign Key to the Album model without `null=True` it won't allow you to create a new Song without an Album model.

There has to be some kind of business logic to know whether a song belongs to an album. In my opinon you should have these 2 in separate endpoints.

When creating a Song you should be able to select from a list albums that it may or may not belong to based on a genre.

Anyways, you can get past this with just adding `null=True` on the the album Foreign key attribute in your Song model.